# Is there a parser and object model for ASPX and ASCX files?

Tags: asp.net, parsing

I'm looking for any resources concerning an ASPX file parser and object model.

I'm trying to read, modify an write ASPX and ASCX files. I tried SGMLReader/XmlDocument, but this does not accept the "<% ... %>" statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't for the life of me fathom *why* you'd be trying to do this, but you might want to look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

> "This is an agile HTML parser that
>   builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually
>   don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is
>   a .NET code library that allows you to
>   parse "out of the web" HTML files. The
>   parser is very tolerant with "real
>   world" malformed HTML. The object
>   model is very similar to what proposes
>   System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or
>   streams)."

Comment: I know, this is nothing common. It's for kind of importing/exporting purpose.

Comment: Just checked it. It's a nice library. Though it's not suitable for parsing aspx. Maybe with some modifications.

Answer (score 1):

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) can parse C#, both as full files and in fragments (e.g., the stuff inside the <% %> brackets) and can parse HTML both in clean and dirty format (the stuff you really see in HTML files).  DMS automatically produces trees ("DOM models") for what it parses.

With minor bit of effort, and HTML dialect with <% %> would be easy to define, and then one could parse ASPX files.   We've done essentially this for PHP already.

Comment: I think this would be a good solution. But currently it's to expensive.